# On window unload function not executing

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried various solutions to send a message when a user close his window but nothing is working.
I have come up with this code but the function is not executing. Have I done something wrong ?

```html
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { 
           e.preventDefault(); 
            e.returnValue = ''; 
            pubnub.publish({
                    channel:  'Logs',
                    message:input2.value + " has left the chat",
                    x: (input.value = '')
                });
        }); 
    </script>
```

The code is in the body.

Comment: Do you see anything in the console?

Comment: I using Repl.it and there is no error in the console.